# Can I fly from Amsterdam to Frankfurt on Lufthansa with just a Residence Permit?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, us-citizens, ams, lufthansa

[US Citizen] I lost my passport but have my Dutch residence permit and am flying from Amsterdam to Frankfurt this coming Sunday with Lufthansa. I have an appointment at the Consulate to get a new passport but I am afraid it won't be created/in in time.

I have a copy of my passport, my residence permit and my Dutch driver's license to prove my identity.

Comment: @pnuts: The discussion you are linking to is from 2008. LH may practice this differently from airport to airport, but at least within the last few years, I've never had to show an id to check-in luggage when flying within the Schengen area. Since 2003, I regularly fly out of Munich and have not once since then showed id when flying with Lufthansa.

Comment: Is the residence permit one of the ones that follow the same layout as the ID cards, that is information on nationality, photo and in case of the residence card the country of residence and the length of permitted stay (or something like the time the card is valid for if max length of stay longer)? In that case it might be enough in itself, not sure though.

Answer (score 3):

Even if there is no regular immigration check when travelling between Schengen countries, German alien law requires you as a non-EEA citizen to have a valid passport when entering Germany, also when crossing an 'open' border from another Schengen member state. Since Netherlands is one of the main sources of illegal drugs and narcotics in Germany, I have the impression that customs checks are more likely when entering from Netherlands than from many other countries. If you are picked for a random check, German customs is likely to ask for your passport as well.

I have never flown with Lufthansa from Amsterdam and practice may differ from airport to airport, but the last few years, I have never experienced an id check when flying with Lufthansa on intra-Schengen flights from other airports. According to Lufthansa's ['General Conditions for Carriage'](http://www.lufthansa.com/mediapool/pdf/34/media_866734.pdf) §13.2 you are however expected to be able to present all travel documents required to enter the destination country, which in this case is a valid passport.

Comment: @pnuts: I am not sure what you are asking about, since I didn't write anything about residence permits. Generally, having any kind of residence permit from another EEA country does not free a non-EEA citizen from having a valid passport when entering and staying in Germany.

Comment: @pnuts: I am not 100% sure what kind of id they are referring to, since the id must be recognized in Germany and for foreigners the recognized documents are restricted to passports or for EEA citizens, their national id cards. There might be some EEA countries issuing id cards to permanent residents, even if they are not citizens of the residing country. In any case, the Dutch residence permit or a Dutch drivers license are *not* recognized as id cards in Germany.